# How to create GUI in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i am trying to get following screen in android please help me how to get below attched screen.
[image]

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: i am trying with image button but unable to get

Comment: @hars post the xml layout you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What else is in the GUI please show the complete GUI pic or the code you have tried You can use a textView add an ImageButton or Button both will do for setting the Background to the GUI use `android:background="@drawable/ur_background_name"` in the Layout if you dont know about the layouts...
then read [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) but here you can use the Linear Layout with vertical orientation and then use TextView and then Button or ImageButton and add background to it, please make sure that it is an button only and not the spinner, Spinner is basically the dropdown list on clicking it, You can also use style for the button, for that create shape XML file in drawable folder
and write code given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#545253" 
    android:endColor="#000000"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="15dp" />
  <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#eecc68" />
</shape>
```